# Dynamic compilation of multiple Scala classes at runtime

Tags: java, scala, reflection, runtime, scala-reflect

I know I can compile individual "snippets" in Scala using the Toolbox like this:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Compiler {
  val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("hello!")"""))
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can compile more than just "snippets", i.e., classes that refer to each other? Like this:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Compiler {
  private val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

  val a: String =
    """
      |package pkg {
      |
      |class A {
      |def compute(): Int = 42
      |}}
    """.stripMargin

  val b: String =
    """
      |import pkg._
      |
      |class B {
      |def fun(): Unit = {
      |    new A().compute()
      |}
      |}
    """.stripMargin

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val compiledA = tb.parse(a)
    val compiledB = tb.parse(b)
    tb.eval(compiledB)
  }
}
```

Obviously, my snippet doesn't work as I have to tell the toolbox how to resolve "A" somehow:

> Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:
>
> not found: type A

Answer (score 4):

Try

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

val a = q"""
          class A {
            def compute(): Int = 42
          }"""

val symbA = tb.define(a)

val b = q"""
          class B {
            def fun(): Unit = {
              new $symbA().compute()
            }
          }"""

tb.eval(b)
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBox.scala#L131-L138

---

In cases more complex than those the toolbox can handle, you can always run the compiler manually

```scala
import scala.reflect.internal.util.{AbstractFileClassLoader, BatchSourceFile}
import scala.reflect.io.{AbstractFile, VirtualDirectory}
import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Settings}
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val a: String =
  """
    |package pkg {
    |
    |class A {
    |  def compute(): Int = 42
    |}}
""".stripMargin

val b: String =
  """
    |import pkg._
    |
    |class B {
    |  def fun(): Unit = {
    |    println(new A().compute())
    |  }
    |}
""".stripMargin

val directory = new VirtualDirectory("(memory)", None)
compileCode(List(a, b), List(), directory)
val runtimeMirror = createRuntimeMirror(directory, runtime.currentMirror)
val bInstance = instantiateClass("B", runtimeMirror)
runClassMethod("B", runtimeMirror, "fun", bInstance) // 42

def compileCode(sources: List[String], classpathDirectories: List[AbstractFile], outputDirectory: AbstractFile): Unit = {
  val settings = new Settings
  classpathDirectories.foreach(dir => settings.classpath.prepend(dir.toString))
  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(outputDirectory)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val global = new Global(settings)
  val files = sources.zipWithIndex.map { case (code, i) => new BatchSourceFile(s"(inline-$i)", code) }
  (new global.Run).compileSources(files)
}

def instantiateClass(className: String, runtimeMirror: Mirror, arguments: Any*): Any = {
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticClass(className)
  val classType = classSymbol.typeSignature
  val constructorSymbol = classType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val classMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
  val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
  constructorMirror(arguments: _*)
}

def runClassMethod(className: String, runtimeMirror: Mirror, methodName: String, classInstance: Any, arguments: Any*): Any = {
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticClass(className)
  val classType = classSymbol.typeSignature
  val methodSymbol = classType.decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(classInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(arguments: _*)
}

//def runObjectMethod(objectName: String, runtimeMirror: Mirror, methodName: String, arguments: Any*): Any = {
//  val objectSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticModule(objectName)
//  val objectModuleMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(objectSymbol)
//  val objectInstance = objectModuleMirror.instance
//  val objectType = objectSymbol.typeSignature
//  val methodSymbol = objectType.decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
//  val objectInstanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(objectInstance)
//  val methodMirror = objectInstanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
//  methodMirror(arguments: _*)
//}

def createRuntimeMirror(directory: AbstractFile, parentMirror: Mirror): Mirror = {
  val classLoader = new AbstractFileClassLoader(directory, parentMirror.classLoader)
  universe.runtimeMirror(classLoader)
}
```

[dynamically parse json in flink map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111895/dynamically-parse-json-in-flink-map/)

[Tensorflow in Scala reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783153/tensorflow-in-scala-reflection/)

[How to eval code that uses InterfaceStability annotation (that fails with "illegal cyclic reference involving class InterfaceStability")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976254/how-to-eval-code-that-uses-interfacestability-annotation-that-fails-with-illeg)

Comment: This works, thanks. But what if I wanted to have import statements in `a`? That leads to a type mismatch as `a` is then no longer an `Compiler.tb.u.ImplDef` but becomes a regular `reflect.runtime.universe.Tree`