# Scala reflection: compile akka actor with protobuf

Tags: java, scala, reflection, akka, toolbox

I am trying to compile an Actor with DynamicMessage with Scala Reflection Toolbox

The actor code looks like

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val actorCode =
  """
    |import akka.actor._
    |import com.google.protobuf._
    |class SimpleActor extends Actor {
    |override def receive: Receive = {
    | case dynamicMessage: DynamicMessage => println("Dynamic message received!")
    | case _  => println("Whatever!")  // the default, catch-all
    |  }
    |}
    |object SimpleActor {
    |def props() : Props = Props(new SimpleActor())
    |}
    |
    |
    |return SimpleActor.props()
    |""".stripMargin
val tree = toolbox.parse(actorCode)
toolbox.compile(tree)().asInstanceOf[Props]
```

I get the error

```
reflective compilation has failed:

illegal cyclic reference involving type T
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

illegal cyclic reference involving type T
```

If I run the code outside of the Toolbox it compiles and works fine.
The error is given from the line

```
case dynamicMessage: DynamicMessage => println("Dynamic message received!")
```

Anyone knows the nature of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In Scala even without reflective compilation there are [bugs](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20illegal%20cyclic%20reference%20involving%20type%20T) in combination of scala-java interop and F-bounded polymorphism:

[scalac reports error on valid Java class: illegal cyclic reference involving type T](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4744)

and others.

And parents of `com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage` explore [F-bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f-bounded-polymorphism%2Bscala?tab=Votes):

```
DynamicMessage 
  <: AbstractMessage
       <: AbstractMessageLite[_,_] (such inheritance is allowed in Java but not in Scala) 
            [M <: AbstractMessageLite[M, B],
             B <: AbstractMessageLite.Builder[M, B]]
                                        [M <: AbstractMessageLite[M, B],
                                         B <: AbstractMessageLite.Builder[M, B]]
                                                                    <: MessageLite.Builder
                                                                                     <: MessageLiteOrBuilder
                                                                                     <: Cloneable
            <: MessageLite
                 <: MessageLiteOrBuilder
       <: Message
            <: MessageLite...
            <: MessageOrBuilder
                 <: MessageLiteOrBuilder
```

But without reflective compilation your code compiles. So this is a bug in combination of reflective compilation, scala-java interop and F-bounded polymorphism.

A workaround is to use real compiler instead of toolbox:

```scala
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
// libraryDependencies += "com.github.os72" % "protobuf-dynamic" % "1.0.1"
import com.github.os72.protobuf.dynamic.{DynamicSchema, MessageDefinition}
import com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage
import scala.reflect.internal.util.{AbstractFileClassLoader, BatchSourceFile}
import scala.reflect.io.{AbstractFile, VirtualDirectory}
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Settings}

val actorCode = """
  |import akka.actor._
  |import com.google.protobuf._
  |
  |class SimpleActor extends Actor {
  |  override def receive: Receive = {
  |    case dynamicMessage: DynamicMessage => println("Dynamic message received!")
  |    case _  => println("Whatever!")  // the default, catch-all
  |  }
  |}
  |
  |object SimpleActor {
  |    def props() : Props = Props(new SimpleActor())
  |}
  |""".stripMargin

val directory = new VirtualDirectory("(memory)", None)
val runtimeMirror = createRuntimeMirror(directory, runtime.currentMirror)
compileCode(actorCode, List(), directory)
val props = runObjectMethod("SimpleActor", runtimeMirror, "props")
  .asInstanceOf[Props]

val actorSystem = ActorSystem("actorSystem")
val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(props, "helloActor")

val msg = makeDynamicMessage()

actor ! "hello" // Whatever!
actor ! msg // Dynamic message received!

actorSystem.terminate()

//see (*)
def makeDynamicMessage(): DynamicMessage = {
  val schemaBuilder = DynamicSchema.newBuilder
  schemaBuilder.setName("PersonSchemaDynamic.proto")

  val msgDef = MessageDefinition.newBuilder("Person")
    .addField("required", "int32", "id", 1)
    .build

  schemaBuilder.addMessageDefinition(msgDef)
  val schema = schemaBuilder.build

  val msgBuilder = schema.newMessageBuilder("Person")
  val msgDesc = msgBuilder.getDescriptorForType
  msgBuilder
    .setField(msgDesc.findFieldByName("id"), 1)
    .build
}

def compileCode(
  code: String, 
  classpathDirectories: List[AbstractFile], 
  outputDirectory: AbstractFile
): Unit = {
  val settings = new Settings
  classpathDirectories.foreach(dir => settings.classpath.prepend(dir.toString))
  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(outputDirectory)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val global = new Global(settings)
  (new global.Run).compileSources(List(new BatchSourceFile("(inline)", code)))
}

def runObjectMethod(
  objectName: String,
  runtimeMirror: Mirror, 
  methodName: String, 
  arguments: Any*
): Any = {
  val objectSymbol         = runtimeMirror.staticModule(objectName)
  val objectModuleMirror   = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(objectSymbol)
  val objectInstance       = objectModuleMirror.instance
  val objectType           = objectSymbol.typeSignature
  val methodSymbol         = objectType.decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val objectInstanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror         = objectInstanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(arguments: _*)
}

def createRuntimeMirror(directory: AbstractFile, parentMirror: Mirror): Mirror = {
  val classLoader = new AbstractFileClassLoader(directory, parentMirror.classLoader)
  universe.runtimeMirror(classLoader)
}
```

[Tensorflow in Scala reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783153/tensorflow-in-scala-reflection) (here was a similar situation with a bug in combination of reflective compilation, Scala-Java interop, and path-dependent types)

[Dynamic compilation of multiple Scala classes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922911/dynamic-compilation-of-multiple-scala-classes-at-runtime)

[How to eval code that uses InterfaceStability annotation (that fails with "illegal cyclic reference involving class InterfaceStability")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976254/how-to-eval-code-that-uses-interfacestability-annotation-that-fails-with-illeg) (also "illegal cyclic reference" during reflective compilation)

[Scala Presentation Compiler - Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538791/scala-presentation-compiler-minimal-example)

(*) [Protocol buffer objects generated at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836727/protocol-buffer-objects-generated-at-runtime)