# How can I run generated code during script runtime?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, scala-compiler, runtime-compilation

During the running of a scala script, I would like it to generate some code and execute this.

I thought I had found two examples online that might work, but they aren't successful

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import java.io.{File, FileWriter}

  def runstuff() = {

    val fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("temporaryScalaFile.scala"))
    fileWriter.write("println(\"hello\")")
    fileWriter.close()
    temporaryScalaFile.scala

    val cm = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
    val str = tb.eval(tb.parse("new String(\"Yo\")"))
    println(str)

  }
```

These are perhaps out of date examples.

Does anyone have a working one or a fix?

Comment: Why do you think they aren't successful? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/xT7scU9BTbWtsFw8Y8wcbQ What is current behavior and what is desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll adopt to Scala 2 my answer in [How to compile and execute scala code at run-time in Scala3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945320/how-to-compile-and-execute-scala-code-at-run-time-in-scala3)

- For example you can use [Li Haoyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871202/li-haoyi)'s [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/)

```scala
ammonite.Main(verboseOutput = false).runCode("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % "2.5.4" cross CrossVersion.full
```

- Also you can use standard Scala 2 REPL [interpreter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.9/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/shell/Scripted.html)

```scala
scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.Scripted()
  .eval("""System.out.println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- You can use Scala 2 reflective [Toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes)

```scala
val tb = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox(scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror).mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("Hello, world!")"""))
// Hello, world!
```

or

```scala
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox // implicit

val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("Hello, world!")"""))
// Hello, world!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- You can use `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter`

```scala
val settings = new scala.tools.nsc.Settings
settings.usejavacp.value = true
new scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain(settings,
  new scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.ReplReporterImpl(settings)
).interpret("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- If you have a `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Tree` `q"..."` rather than plain string then you don't need to parse

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Quasiquote // implicit for q"..." interpolator
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox               // implicit for .eval

scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  .eval(q"""println("Hello, World!")""") // Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- If you have a `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Expr` `reify {...}` (a statically typed wrapper over a tree) rather than plain string then you also don't need to parse

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  .eval(reify{ println("Hello, World!") }.tree) 
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- All of the above is to run Scala 2 code in Scala 2. If we want to run Scala 3 code in Scala 2 then we can use standard Scala 3 REPL [interpreter](https://javadoc.io/static/org.scala-lang/scala3-compiler_3/3.2.0/dotty/tools/repl/ScriptEngine.html)

```scala
(new dotty.tools.repl.ScriptEngine).eval("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value %% "scala3-compiler" % "3.1.3" cross CrossVersion.for2_13Use3
scalacOptions += "-Ytasty-reader"
```

- Also you can use [JSR223](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr223/index.html) scripting. Depending on whether you have `scala-compiler` or `scala3-compiler` in your classpath you will run Scala 2 or Scala 3 (one of the two above script engines: Scala 2 `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.Scripted` or Scala 3 `dotty.tools.repl.ScriptEngine`). If you have both the dependency added first wins.

```scala
new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager(getClass.getClassLoader)
  .getEngineByName("scala")
  .eval("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

If you'd like to have a better control what dependency is used (without re-importing the project) you can use Coursier and specify class loader

```scala
import coursier._ // libraryDependencies += "io.get-coursier" %% "coursier" % "2.1.0-M6-53-gb4f448130"
val files = Fetch()
  .addDependencies(
    Dependency(Module(Organization("org.scala-lang"), ModuleName("scala-compiler")), "2.13.9"),
    // Dependency(Module(Organization("org.scala-lang"), ModuleName("scala3-compiler_3")), "3.2.0"),
  )
  .run()

val classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(
  files.map(_.toURI.toURL).toArray,
  /*getClass.getClassLoader*/null // ignoring current classpath
)
new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager(classLoader)
  .getEngineByName("scala")
  .eval("""
    type T = List[Option[A]] forSome {type A} // Scala 2
    //type T = [A] =>> [B] =>> (A, B) // Scala 3
    System.out.println("Hello, World!")
  """)
// Hello, World!
```

- You can implement Eval in Scala 2 yourself using actual compiler

```scala
import scala.reflect.internal.util.{AbstractFileClassLoader, BatchSourceFile}
import scala.reflect.io.{AbstractFile, VirtualDirectory}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{Mirror, TermName}
import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Settings}

val code =
  s"""
     |package mypackage
     |
     |object Main {
     |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     |    println("Hello, World!")
     |  }
     |}""".stripMargin

val directory = new VirtualDirectory("(memory)", None)
val runtimeMirror = createRuntimeMirror(directory, runtime.currentMirror)
compileCode(code, List(), directory)
runObjectMethod("mypackage.Main", runtimeMirror, "main", Array.empty[String])
// Hello, World!

def compileCode(
                 code: String,
                 classpathDirectories: List[AbstractFile],
                 outputDirectory: AbstractFile
               ): Unit = {
  val settings = new Settings
  classpathDirectories.foreach(dir => settings.classpath.prepend(dir.toString))
  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(outputDirectory)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val global = new Global(settings)
  val run = new global.Run
  run.compileSources(List(new BatchSourceFile("(inline)", code)))
  // val unit = run.units.next()
  // println("source=" + unit.source.content.mkString)
  // println("typed tree=" + unit.body)
}

def runObjectMethod(
                     objectName: String,
                     runtimeMirror: Mirror,
                     methodName: String,
                     arguments: Any*
                   ): Any = {
  val objectSymbol         = runtimeMirror.staticModule(objectName)
  val objectModuleMirror   = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(objectSymbol)
  val objectInstance       = objectModuleMirror.instance
  val objectType           = objectSymbol.typeSignature
  val methodSymbol         = objectType.decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val objectInstanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror         = objectInstanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(arguments: _*)
}

def createRuntimeMirror(directory: AbstractFile, parentMirror: Mirror): Mirror = {
  val classLoader = new AbstractFileClassLoader(directory, parentMirror.classLoader)
  universe.runtimeMirror(classLoader)
}
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- Also [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) [Semanticdb](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html) has method `scala.meta.interactive.InteractiveSemanticdb.newCompiler()` returning a `scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global` extending above `scala.tools.nsc.Global`.

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
// adding as a dependency, not a compiler plugin
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" % "semanticdb-scalac" % "4.6.0" cross CrossVersion.full
```

[Scala reflection: compile akka actor with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302376/scala-reflection-compile-akka-actor-with-protobuf)

[Dynamic compilation of multiple Scala classes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922911/dynamic-compilation-of-multiple-scala-classes-at-runtime)

[How to eval code that uses InterfaceStability annotation (that fails with "illegal cyclic reference involving class InterfaceStability")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976254/how-to-eval-code-that-uses-interfacestability-annotation-that-fails-with-illeg)

[Tensorflow in Scala reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783153/tensorflow-in-scala-reflection)

[Scala Presentation Compiler - Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538791/scala-presentation-compiler-minimal-example)

[What is "Scala Presentation Compiler"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468367/what-is-scala-presentation-compiler)

["eval" in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala)